# I need to get column type and insert it in table(label)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a `windows form application` that manipulate data from `SQL server`. I'm trying to get column type and put it in the table so it can be something like that`(Label{columnName}{columnType} Textbox)`. 
The query is:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'comboBox1.SelectedItem' 
AND  COLUMN_NAME = '{labels[i].Text}'
```

I need only to understand how can I put that query in a value with the result and add it to my `tableLayout`.

Trying that now, but it's not executed

```
using (form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True"))
{
    form1.conn.Open();
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(getSqlTypes, form1.conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                labels[i] = new Label();
                labels[i].Text = (string)reader["TABLE_NAME"];
                tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(2, k++));
            }
        }
    }

    form1.conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened with the following code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqladapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"{getSqlTypes}", form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True"));
                DataSet dt = new DataSet();
                sqladapter.Fill(dt);
                labels[i] = new Label();
                labels[i].Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(2, k++));
                tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
                getSqlTypes = $"SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{comboBox1.SelectedItem}' AND COLUMN_NAME = ";
```